# Check if service advertised successfully

Tags: ros, ros-service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
is there  a way to check (ex. get a bool returned) if a service has been successfully advertised?

My node advertises multiple services, and it would be usefull to be able to check, if every service is advertised properly and signal to the user in case sth. went wrong.

Is it possible to get some information from ros::ServiceServer? Does it make sense to maybe use C++ try/catch mechanism? Or maybe am I completely wrong and should assume, that nothing can go wrong when advertising a service? (My node basically advertises services for functions of a third parity lib and it is pretty important, that all functions of that lib are accessible)

thanks for Your input :-)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211992/check-if-service-advertised-successfully/) by [Reiner](https://answers.ros.org/users/22377/reiner/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2015-06-24

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is `ros::service::exists` for that: http://docs.ros.org/api/roscpp/html/namespaceros_1_1service.html#a561507ffbd6ce6536bac5c963658038f

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2015-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Reiner](https://answers.ros.org/users/22377/reiner/) on 2015-06-25**:
Exactly what I needed, cheers.